# Saving function in swift

Tags: swift

I have made an app which has 15 levels, in which each level has 3 stages. 
So overall I have 45 scenes/viewcontrollers.

I'm trying to figure out how I can create a saving function, so that if you close the app on the phone and you open it later, it will remember which level/stage you were at. I just started with swift and I am also wondering if this is way too ahead of my programming level to create this, but hopefully it might be more simple than I thought?

Comment: There are several possibilities: `Core Data`, `Realm`, `NSCoding`, writing to `JSON`, writing to `plist`, writing to text file and if it is not a lot data, writing to `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: It's simpler than you think. If you're just starting, go look at `NSUserDefaults` and don't worry about all the other more complicated solutions. `NSUserDefaults` will do just about everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the desired pieces are small, which simply saving level/stage text info would be, NSUserDefaults is the way to go.

Core Data is a great technology, but takes a bit of learning and is overkill for only saving a tiny bit of information. Been using NSUserDefaults myself a bunch lately, and it's working well.

```
//in Swift:

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

//send data to NSUserDefaults:
defaults.setObject(desiredValue, forKey: stringNameOfValue)

//retrieve data from NSUserDefaults:
desiredValue = defaults.objectForKey(stringNameOfValue)
```

for more info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/

Comment: Do not use `setValue:forKey:` (that's a KVC method) in this case. The dedicated method is `setObject:forKey:`

Comment: You're welcome. And `pullDictValue` is not really a supported method ;-)

Comment: yeah, just caught that. dang it. amending too.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, `NSUserDefaults` is a great option for the scale of data storage you're looking at. But another good option is to use [`NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore). That class works similarly, but adds the ability to sync the small data items you're saving to iCloud.

There's [a little bit more](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH7) you have to think about when using iCloud KVS, but it's almost the same as using `NSUserDefaults`. And for that tiny bit of extra effort, your users get a huge win: when you close the app on your phone, you can open it later, on the same iPhone or *on your iPad, Apple TV, Mac, iPod touch, other iPhone, etc*, and still have it remember where you left off.